# Migrated questions aren't appearing on the Questions tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

On Board and Cardgames at the moment, the newest question is one that has been migrated from another site: [Will the Star Wars LCG game have force power cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8189/will-the-star-wars-lcg-game-have-force-power-cards)

This question is at the top of [the homepage](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/), but it doesn't appear at all on the [Questions->newest](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions) tab, although it does appear under '[active](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)'.

Is this a bug? Surely a migrated question should still count as 'new'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrated questions only count as "new" as in the freshness of today if they were originally posted today.

If a migrated question coming in was created months ago, then it will appear similarly in that block of time with the other questions if you're sorting by "newest".

Sort by active and you'll see it listed under the time it was pushed to its new home.

That CCG question so far is appearing in both the Newest and Active tabs for the relevant timestamps accorded.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's further down the page on the newest tab, because it was asked many hours ago. Understood.